# node.js - cannot import packages that are installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I am trying to import `moments` into my `main.js` folder and am having difficulty.
I installed with `npm install moment --save`. I have tried both the `require('moment')` and `import moment from 'moment'` syntax. When I tried using `require` I got errors that I don't remember exactly, but they were common. I have scoured YouTube and SO and none of the solutions have solved it. Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss style.css -w",
    "devserver": "live-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

in the `index.html` file I have `type="module"` to allow ES6 imports. What am I doing wrong?

sorry! forgot the error I am getting (currently)
`TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: moment`

when trying to use `require`:
`ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: I'm sorry but you omitted the crucial part of your question which is the actual error you run into. Could you please reproduce the issue again and update your question with the actual error you get? I mean, if the error was "that common" you wouldn't be asking the question in the first place, am I right?

Comment: i added in the current error I am recieving. the other errors were for trying to use `require` but id rather just use `import` syntax if possible

Comment: you should not use require when you switch to ES6 modules which you did by adding `"type": "module"` to your package.json file. The correct syntax to importing moment.js using modules is: `import moment from 'moment';`. Try importing it that way and let's see what the error is then.

Comment: I am using `import moment from 'moment'` and that is giving me the errors. which is the root cause of my confusion.

Comment: I also don't get why you have an explicit `requirejs` dependency in your package.json. Try removing that one, the require syntax is built in into node.js. Also make sure you are using the latest version of node, the ES6 modules syntax is not supported by older versions of node.

Comment: also, DON'T use both the require AND the import syntax. You have to use ONE of both, in your case, you should use ONLY the `import moment from 'moment'` syntax, remove all other uses of the require syntax. This is probably your main problem.

Comment: I do have the latest version of npm. did `npm upgrade` just to ensure. `npm -v` gave `6.14.6`. removing the `requirejs` from `package.json` did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220866/discussion-between-stvn-and-nos-codemos).

Comment: ok thank you. ill see you in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after digging a bit deeper, let's summarize:

In your case you only want to use `moment.js` in a `main.js` file that you reference in a `index.html` file using a script tag. This has nothing to do with `node.js` other than the fact that you can use `npm` to download the moment dependency. To achieve what you are trying to do I would suggest doing the following:

Install the moment dependency using npm

```
npm install moment
```

Copy over the `moment.js` file from the `node_modules/moment/lib` folder (not the src!) to a folder in your project (fe. scripts). You could do this manually or with a script/task runner.

in the main.js file, you reference the file using

```
import moment from './moment.js';
```

and in your index.html file you reference the main.js file using

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

As we discussed. This is some manual labor but for doing some quick tryouts, this can sometimes be enough. If you were to start to actually build a full sized application I would strongly suggest you to add a module bundler like `webpack` who can take all of this work off your hands.